# VSCode highlighting failure of python imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch, highlight

As you can see in the screenshot above, my Visual Studio Code has some trouble rendering highlights, only those of the imports such as `numpy` and `torch`.

[image]

This happened after I rebooted my laptop, before which everything was normal.

The code runs well, but I'm just annoyed by not having proper highlighting.

(And also it's mysterious since all I did was just reboot my laptop...)

I have tried to change the language server from `Default` to `Pylance`, and also reinstalled `Pylance`. However, neither worked.

Comment: Can you solve the problem if you disable all extensions and only keep python and pylance?

Comment: Have you tried restarting vscode?

Comment: possibly related on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4429